# For every x, y ∈ IN = {1, . . . , N} define K(x, y) = min{x, y}. Prove that K is a valid kernel

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, svm, kernel-trick

I need to prove K is a valid Kernel.
x and y are positive integers, and K is the minimum of x and y.
I know I should prove K positive definite. But May I see how.

Comment: to prove it symmetric is easy; k(x,y) = min{x,y} = min{y,x} = k(y,x)
but how can I prove positive semi-definite: I need to show v^{T}Kv > 0
or show that sum(sum(c_x c_y K(x,y))) >= 0

Comment: x, y belong to I = {1, 2, , ..., N}

Comment: Immediate proof: $K$ is the covariance matrix of Brownian motion on $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal X$ be any subset of $\{1...N\}$, and $|\mathcal X|=n,$ and $x_i,x_j$ be any two elements from this set.

We can write $\min(x_i,x_j)$ as below:
$$\min(x_i,x_j)=\int_0^N \mathbb 1(t\leq x_i)\mathbb 1(t\leq x_j)dt$$

The reason of this equality is straightforward. The first indicator function will be $1$ until $x_i$; and the second indicator function is $1$ until $x_j$. The multiplication will be $1$ if both are $1$, which means until the minimum of $x_i$ and $x_j$. The integral then can be written as
$$\begin{align}\int_0^N\mathbb 1(t\leq x_i)\mathbb 1(t\leq x_j)dt&=\int_0^{\min(x_i,x_j)}\mathbb 1(t\leq x_i)\mathbb 1(t\leq x_j)dt\\&=\int_0^{\min(x_i,x_j)}1\times 1\times dt\\&=\min(x_i,x_j)\end{align}$$

Then, we substitute in to the PSD requirement:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j \min(x_i,x_j)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j \int_0^N \mathbb 1(t\leq x_i)\mathbb 1(t\leq x_j)dt \\&=\int_0^N \underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\mathbb 1(t\leq x_i)\right)}_{M(t)}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\mathbb 1(t\leq x_j)\right)}_{M(t)}dt\\&=\int_0^NM(t)M(t)dt=\int_0^NM(t)^2dt\geq 0\end{align}$$

Both multiplicands are equal because both summations range from $1$ to $n$. We can also change the order of summations and integrations according to [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) (in short, the sums and integrals are finite).

This covers PSD property and you've already mentioned the symmetric property in your comment.

Comment: Can you please explain how you wrote the min in an integral form.

Comment: It's a common trick. Do you understand it equals to min(x,y)?

Comment: No, I didn't really get it

Comment: I have added some explanation for it. Let me know if it's more understandable.

Comment: yeah it is vert clear, thank you sir!

Comment: Does the same work if x and y belong to I_{N} = {1, 2, ..., N}?
I is the identity function size NxN

Comment: Yes, the proof already assumes it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_N, \ldots$ be a sequence of independent zero-mean unit variance random variables.  For instance, each $B_i$ could be a Rademacher variable that has a $1/2$ chance of being $+1$ and a $1/2$ chance of being $-1.$

Let $X_i = B_1 + B_2 + \cdots + B_i$ be the partial sum.  The sequence $(X_i)$ is an example of a *random walk.*  We are going to compute the covariance matrix of this walk.  The algebra is simple, but I will give all the details just to be perfectly clear.

Because each $X_i$ is a sum of independent (therefore uncorrelated) variables, its variance is the sum of the variances of its components, whence $$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \operatorname{Var}(B_1) + \operatorname{Var}(B_2) + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}(B_i)  = i.$$

Morever, when $j\gt i$ the additional terms in $X_j$ (namely, $B_{i+1} + \cdots + B_j$) are independent of $X_i$ and therefore uncorrelated with it, showing that

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_j) &= \operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_i + (X_j-X_i))\\
& = \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_i) + \operatorname{Cov}(X_i, X_j-X_i) \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(X_i) + 0 \\
&= i.
\end{aligned}$$

Since covariance is symmetric, $$\operatorname{Cov}(X_j,X_i) = \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = i.$$

A convenient way to express all these results is

> $$\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = \min(i,j) = K(i,j).$$

**Because $K$ is a covariance matrix and all covariance matrices are positive semi-definite, it is a kernel,** *QED.*

Comment: Quite interesting perspective! There is small typo, it should be like the following I believe: $\operatorname{var}(X_i)=\operatorname{var}(B_1)+...$

Comment: @gunes LOL -- I am constantly surprised at what I manage to overlook.